# telgif: inverse figlet

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

`figlet` is utility that converts plain text to an ascii-art representation for use in banners and the like.  For example:

```
$ figlet "CODE GOLF"
  ____ ___  ____  _____    ____  ___  _     _____ 
 / ___/ _ \|  _ \| ____|  / ___|/ _ \| |   |  ___|
| |  | | | | | | |  _|   | |  _| | | | |   | |_   
| |__| |_| | |_| | |___  | |_| | |_| | |___|  _|  
 \____\___/|____/|_____|  \____|\___/|_____|_|    
                                                  
$
```

Write a program or function that takes the ascii-art output from `figlet` and returns it to its original plain text.

It may be helpful to you to install `figlet`.  I have version 2.2.5 which is what you get if you `sudo apt-get install figlet` on Ubuntu 14.04.  This figlet actually has several "fonts".  For the purposes of this context, we will just be dealing with the default `standard` font.

Input text will be no more that 80 characters wide, and will have been generated from plain text containing only the uppercase characters and space.

Your program may not call `figlet` or its source code in any way.

#### Example

Input:

```
    _    ____   ____ ____  _____ _____ ____ _   _ ___ 
   / \  | __ ) / ___|  _ \| ____|  ___/ ___| | | |_ _|
  / _ \ |  _ \| |   | | | |  _| | |_ | |  _| |_| || | 
 / ___ \| |_) | |___| |_| | |___|  _|| |_| |  _  || | 
/_/   \_\____/ \____|____/|_____|_|   \____|_| |_|___|
                                                      
     _ _  ___     __  __ _   _  ___  ____   ___  ____  
    | | |/ / |   |  \/  | \ | |/ _ \|  _ \ / _ \|  _ \ 
 _  | | ' /| |   | |\/| |  \| | | | | |_) | | | | |_) |
| |_| | . \| |___| |  | | |\  | |_| |  __/| |_| |  _ < 
 \___/|_|\_\_____|_|  |_|_| \_|\___/|_|    \__\_\_| \_\
                                                       
 ____ _____ _   ___     ____        ____  ____   _______
/ ___|_   _| | | \ \   / /\ \      / /\ \/ /\ \ / /__  /
\___ \ | | | | | |\ \ / /  \ \ /\ / /  \  /  \ V /  / / 
 ___) || | | |_| | \ V /    \ V  V /   /  \   | |  / /_ 
|____/ |_|  \___/   \_/      \_/\_/   /_/\_\  |_| /____|
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQR
STUVWXYZ
```

Input:

```
 ____ _____  _    ____   __        ___    ____  ____  
/ ___|_   _|/ \  |  _ \  \ \      / / \  |  _ \/ ___| 
\___ \ | | / _ \ | |_) |  \ \ /\ / / _ \ | |_) \___ \ 
 ___) || |/ ___ \|  _ <    \ V  V / ___ \|  _ < ___) |
|____/ |_/_/   \_\_| \_\    \_/\_/_/   \_\_| \_\____/
```

Output:

```
STAR WARS
```

---

Note a previous edit of this question allowed inputs containing upper and lower case letters plus numerals.  It was pointed out that this caused several points of ambiguity with certain adjacent character combinations.  It became obvious that I needed to rigorously find a set of characters with no such collisions so that the contest is actually doable.  At first I tried all lowercase letters plus numerals with this shell one-liner:

```
for t in {0..9}{a..z} {a..z}{a..z} {a..z}{0..9} {0..9}{0..9} ; do figlet $t | tr '\n' ':'; echo ; done | sort | uniq -d | tr ':' '\n'
```

This yielded {`j1`, `jl`} and {`i1`, `il`} as ambiguous pairs.  So instead with all uppercase letters (as suggested by @AlexA.), there are no ambiguous pairs:

```
for t in {A-Z} ; do figlet $t | tr '\n' ':'; echo ; done | sort | uniq -d | tr ':' '\n'
```

Comment: I'd suggest a 'you may not call figlet' clause, because otherwise surely the shortest program will iterate over all possible strings, calling figlet on them, and then comparing for equality.

Comment: The source code of figlet can be found in the following git repo: `git://git.debian.org/git/collab-maint/figlet.git` (download with `git clone`).

Comment: Note: this challenge is very difficult to code, let alone code golf.

Comment: `1` and `l` are not identical, but `V1` and `Vl` are.

Comment: `XOX` and `XDX` are still really hard to discern... maybe that's a good kind of challenge, though?

Comment: @Mauris hard, but not impossible :)

Comment: For people who do not have a system that can run figlet, there are various online versions. Search for "figlet online". For example, this one looks fairly straightforward and ad free: http://www.network-science.de/ascii/. Make sure that you choose the "standard" font.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks!  I checked the output and with the standard font, it does seem to match.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, 946 bytes

```
i=>i.split(/\n *\n/).slice(n=0,-1).map(x=>[...(x=x.split`
`)[0]].map((_,i)=>parseInt([0,1,2,3,4].map(j=>"_/\\|".indexOf(x[j][i])+1).join(""),5)).map((n,i,x)=>o[x.slice(i).map(a=>v=v*5+a,v=0).find(v=>o[v])]||"").join``," 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".split(/(?=[A-Z ])/).map(x=>o[n+=parseInt(x.slice(1),36)]=x[0],o={})).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNdc5pAFH33VzA8sQlBdhHFB@yQD9tYW5NotX6NIgu6qICAgJb@dgsCeQiZ6YXZPfecu@cyzF5TDVRPc4nj31k21i@Oa2u653Gej@2jz4Uu8XWGuRC5RTjP2RGfqc4s6mZmVQHn7YimM5bMs3cQcHvVYSK5NeU4LtmjrHpZWYIpP59fVWbBEiC3HNX19GfLZ6Y8C1nECmwt0025RS@qs1lMc8TCetQzmGhqzqdkDm6TBqZNLIamASuCrBtjsYSNEkd7GuUfQzJFlVuBHNyItyobyDzgjMSPCdLCYA7mcZy4XO2WS5am@A4hwTPEYufknb6vI/63eDhN9PV5Ykyae39i9AQkSa/Nh5X9YHxF0sO2h5qvzQ5crYWfCDed7obHXaOLvC4Ov8HasRviX3BV625P49UqHMMxGm/G0DA/oq5gGWOI6jmPePyx4g02hBfzBSVP421tprCt1dte229D99HRHjf4Hjr@/QY/Resn4wl5fX0X9OunPg47Ykj6rpAn6qHW0RAcSGd1AAfuAG0VJK0U5Ck4HAhBwcGjocAQDUItZwYw2hViQ9MGgSi9K5pbQEnwy2yvJm1Lf00JXJ9kbRUE92kzRdWiH/UzlBSkOU69LCqNk7X@hIbHLVmV@SFcuc52KAxrQzyEvGjmEOnNMlnbY1hiFfeonj5puNaQWKZH9vnAN9yRMKqN8EjY7IQgxxLWxU/oNXREXObpYsCYL/JUuZtQc1B9Hyt7at3K75NTXHcIWKEO5nKUzBhry3/@gvxeV5YXwLj64UhcnaENL7nvrq7iNtnp/ZOlMTxLH31DogEAF2qRRrFSaRRETlbilF7E1zSm4iSppjihk/SKKhQVXx9qke9Zkm7Jm55/L4kzl2zJ9OzctSSTru5pzAqYCpnL/6LyDw)

Note that `figlet` by default outputs two trailing blank lines; if those can be
assumed to not exist, like in the challenge examples, the initial `slice` can be
removed for [-10 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZRrc5pAFIa/51cwfGIbguwiijPFDrnYxtomrVar4iCyoKsGCCBgSn97utxspwZm2HOe9@x7FmaXrRmboRUQP7pyPWy/@oFn2WEohBH2DpGQBCSyOe6VqF0ihP6eRFxDd5l3utsAwpPpc6nanQuCQMe01JcXSzAXF4tC5QyeALXrm0Fo37sRNxd5yCNe4pulvlW7rNHQ9YwViIvt9MHh0vl2MScLcAmBsPWIy7Es4GVQduNcnvApdfTmtN2eWDZHSsVUu7Eav5MvTT5WRSA41I@L88J4ARZZRl0Ku@WSZxmxT0h8D7HcP4bHz@tU/Ck/H2f2@mXmzDpP0cx5kJCifOvcrLwb5yNSbnYPqPOt04ertfQV4Y4/2Ih44AxQOMDJJ9g8DBL8A66ag91xulolUzhF080UOtv/o4HkOlOIWhVHIv6/4jtsS4/bR0Tv9vf1Ng97VqsX9qIeDG5963aDr6EfXW/wXbq@c@5QOLT38bB1HOKkLydkGEhVYj43@xaCI@XFHMFRMEI7DSkrDYUaTkZSXDN4cDSYoFFiVWQE030tti1rFMvKSbGCOlSk6Jw@NJXd2VfT4iAiZVsNwae8mWZa6ZfWC1Q0ZPl@61zU2kd3/QaGhx1ZnfMxXAX@biyNm2M8hqK8rUJkd85h8wnDM6oFB/P4RsO1heRzPPFensV2MJEmzQmeSJu9FFexgm35DbyGvozPOVsfKe6DOteuZswC/D1W3ty9VE8np97uEPBSCyzUlJ4x3lN//eZdut2rvX2xfAVcYD8fSGBzrBPSPR/YJu6RvT08uhYn8uwhchQWAPDKGPlVPulYXXVas5P6r1DLF1nBsyLVGb20aNDbKDBj5CyXGUAjKhROZX2jnEo9MiMvyjmTmzSKyhLkIsifhZfOjKlUpKWs58vQy3WUxfmy8rKisgTF3PdM7VXMrTyy6l0ovsiMghvV0nX6WzIaJ1A008uMGle12Uku8B8). Otherwise, make sure the blank lines are
present in the "Input" field on TIO, or the last line of output will be omitted.

### Explanation

At a high level, this scans the strings for patterns, and outputs the ones it
finds.

A single character can have multiple patterns; for example, these are all valid
patterns for `A`: (the first and last column are omitted, as they are not
necessary for matching)

```
   _   
  / \  
 / _ \ 
/ ___ \
_/   \_
```

```
_  _   
_|/ \  
 / _ \ 
/ ___ \
_/   \_
```

```
 _____ 
/ / \ \
 / _ \ 
/ ___ \
_/   \_
```

The first appears in bare `A`s, or uncombined `A`s such as in `AX`, the second
appears in `TA`, and the third appears in e.g. `WAV`:

```
    _      _____  _     __        _____     __
   / \    |_   _|/ \    \ \      / / \ \   / /
  / _ \     | | / _ \    \ \ /\ / / _ \ \ / / 
 / ___ \    | |/ ___ \    \ V  V / ___ \ V /  
/_/   \_\   |_/_/   \_\    \_/\_/_/   \_\_/   
 -------       -------           -------
```

Thus, for every character, there is a pattern for:

- Each triplet of characters with it at the center
- Each pair of characters containing it
- It on it's own

Some of these patterns are identical, for example, the `A`s in `VAV` and `WAV` are
identical, and the `A`s in `AX`, `XA`, and `A` are identical.

Each pattern needs a unique representation, and since this is code golf, it
should be as compact as possible.

Because the mega-characters have a fixed height of 5, but are not fixed-width,
the patterns are defined principally by columns.

First, each of the symbols in the pattern are converted to a single base-5 digit,
where  `_/\|` respectively correspond to 0-4, and other symbols are treated as
spaces.

```
   _   
  / \  
 / _ \ 
/ ___ \
_/   \_

0001000
0020300
0201030
2011103
1200032
```

Then, the 5 base-5 digits in a column are combined to make a single base-5
number.

```
00021, 00202, 02010, 10110, 03010, 00303, 00032
```

Represented in decimal, the column numbers are `11, 52, 255, 655, 380, 78, 16`.

These numbers must be combined into one number that identifies the pattern. The
correct way would be to concatenate all of the base-5 numbers (or, equivalently,
to treat the list of column numbers as a base-3125 number).

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the correct way will not be used, due to a bug that
happened to not break stuff for this set of patterns and is now considered a
byte-saving feature.

Thus, the column numbers are combined into one number that identifies the pattern:

```
   11 * 5^6
+  52 * 5^5
+ 255 * 5^4
+ 655 * 5^3
+ 380 * 5^2
+  78 * 5^1
+  16 * 5^0

= 585531
```

Now, these numbers are inserted into a giant lookup table, along with `0` for  :

```js
{
  0: " ",
  585531: "A",
  591231: "A",
  // ...
}
```

At this point, the table could be serialized and plopped into the code, but it
is not very golfy. Thus, this explanation branches into two parts: matching the
patterns and compressing the lookup table.

### Matching the Patterns

Matching the patterns is fairly simple. First, the input is split into
paragraphs; each paragraph is a line of mega-text. The paragraphs/mega-lines are
converted independently, and then joined again with newlines.

Each mega-line is first converted into an array of column numbers:

```
  ____ ___  ____  _____    ____  ___  _     _____ 
 / ___/ _ \|  _ \| ____|  / ___|/ _ \| |   |  ___|
| |  | | | | | | |  _|   | |  _| | | | |   | |_   
| |__| |_| | |_| | |___  | |_| | |_| | |___|  _|  
 \____\___/|____/|_____|  \____|\___/|_____|_|

[
  120, 253, 746, 756, 756, 871, 253, 746, 756,
  746, 377, 624, 626, 746, 756, 746, 377, 624,
  626, 771, 781, 856, 756, 504,   0, 120, 253,
  746, 756, 771, 776, 624, 253, 746, 756, 746,
  377, 624, 626, 621,   6,   6,   6, 624, 626,
  729, 780, 770, 750, 500
]
```

Then, this array is iterated across; for every number in the array:

1. If this number is in the lookup table, add the corresponding character to the
   string and continue iteration.
2. Multiply the number by `5`, and add the next number in the array. Go to #1,
   and repeat until the number matches or there are no numbers left.

Note that it searches for a character starting at every column, regardless of
the previous matches. Additionally, the only way it finds no character starting
at a column is if it exhaustively checks all possible ending columns to the end
of the array, completely ignoring the fact that no patterns are longer than 12
columns.

After this highly inefficient process completes, the string will be `CODE GOLF`.

### Compressing the Lookup Table

If the lookup table were simply serialized, it would be a whopping 23,094 bytes,
which is clearly unacceptable.

The lookup table is transformed as follows:

```
Original:
  0: " "
  12: A
  63: B
  209: A
  1040: C
  30: A
  512: C

Sorted:
  0: " "
  12: A
  30: A
  63: B
  209: A
  512: C
  1040: C

Difference from last:
  +0: " "
  +12: A
  +18: A
  +33: B
  +146: A
  +303: C
  +528: C

Final (numbers are encoded in base 36):
  " 0AcAiBxA42C8fCeo"
```

The final string is:

```
 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
```

I haven't done much [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity), so if anyone has ideas on how to
compress this further, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: In theory you can save 158 bytes by specifying that the source is in ISO-8859-1, running that long string through `atob`, and substituting `btoa\`<unprintables>\`` for it.

Comment: @Neil Good idea, but unfortunately I can't get the unprintables to work consistently. Also, it seems like the binary string is somehow longer? I don't know how that could be the case, though

Comment: Are you accidentally measuring the binary string in the wrong code page? `atob` generates ISO-8859-1, but you might have been measuring it in UTF-8 by mistake, which would double its length.