# Convert ASCII art numbers to integers

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

[Inspired by this game](https://bubmet.itch.io/intercept)

## Challenge:

Given an ASCII art string representing a number, output that number.
Example:

```
Input:

  &&&&      #####    .====..    .&&&
 $$$$$.    %%   %%   %    % .   +. .
   @@@  .      @@ .  = .  =   . ????
   +++.    &&   &&.  %    %     =   =
   $$$    . @@@@@    #    #  .  ===.
 .$$$$$              .????.

Output: 1306
```

```
Input:

  ====     .$$..      &&&&&&.    .@@@@    ?????
 +++++     &. &           $$    %%   %%  &&   &&
   $$$     .==.          @@ .   @@   @@ .    ??
.  ### .   @  @  .      ==     $$$$$$$$  ??. .??
. .@@@.    .%%.        ==           .$$   &&&&&  .
  $$$$$. .            .%        .    @@ .

Output: 18743
```

Periods are interference, you can ignore them

The complete list of numbers:

```
 &&&& 
%    %
=    =
%    %
#    #
 ????

 &&&&
$$$$$
  @@@
  +++
  $$$
 $$$$$


 #####
++   ++
 #  ##
   @@
  @@    
???????


 #####
%%   %%
    @@
&&   &&
 @@@@@  


   @@@@
 %%   %%
 @@   @@
$$$$$$$$
      $$
      @@ 


###### 
$  
#### 
    + 
    ? 
$$$$$ 


 &&&
+ 
????
=   =
===

&&&&&&
    $$
   @@
  ==
 ==
 %

 $$
&  &
 ==
@  @
 %%


 &&&&
@    @
 &&&&
    $
    &
  +
```

## Rules:

- Your input is a **string** unless your language doesn't have a string type.
- The input is guaranteed to be exactly 6 characters "high." Numbers such as 8 and 3 have a whitespace buffer UNDER the number.
- If you write a function, it MUST return a numerical type.
- The ASCII art can be composed of ANY printable characters in no particular order (remember, you can ignore periods).
- No standard loopholes.
- Your program must handle any arbitrary ASCII number of reasonable length (as long as the result fits within a 32-bit signed integer).
- Input is guaranteed valid, undefined behavior is allowed with bad input.
- This is code-golf, shortest program wins.


  More tests:

```
  $$$$     ######     @@@@  . .  .%%%%    #####
 #####     $ .       =====..  . ##   ##  ++   ++
   +++     ####.       +++.     ==   ==   #  ##
   ===     .   +       ###  .  ========.    @@
  .&&&    .  . ?   . . @@@           ##    @@    .
  %%%%%    $$$$$      #####          @@  ???????

> 15142

 .&&&&.    ??????     @@@@@      .++++
 @    @    + .       ==   ==    %%   %%
 .&&&&.    ####..     =  == .   ++   ++
  .. $         &        $$     $$$$$$$$.
 .   &.      . #       && .          ##
   +.   .  #####     $$$$$$$        .==

> 9524
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the set of valid number characters is `&$@+#%=?`. Are there any other characters that are valid? Will each row in a number always contain the same character?

Comment: @Stephen I updated the question. The numbers can be composed of any printable characters in no particular order.

Comment: Can a period `.` appear as both a part of the character and a part of interference?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork periods are always interference. They are not part of the number.

Comment: I'm not sure that "periods are interference" really adds much to the challenge.

Comment: Is it the case that all digits are 8 characters wide and will have a single leading and (optionally) trailing column of spaces? (the examples seem to adhere to this)

Comment: ...and is the input guaranteed to be 6 characters high? (...or do we need to handle inputs like `863` being only 5 high?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan that is correct (6 high & 8 wide). I've edited the question. The periods are there because my source for the numbers puts them in randomly, so I kept them. It might not add much to the challenge, but it is what it is /shrug

Comment: The 2 in the tests is different to the 2 in the sample digits

Comment: @NickKennedy fixed

Comment: Is the trailing space at the end of the first line of the 0 intentional?

Comment: I think AdmBorkBork's question was not "are periods always interference?" but rather "can there be a period where a non-space character should be?" I assume (as have current answers) that they can only appear where spaces are meant to appear (and hence why I said I din't think it added much to the challenge).

Comment: Is it ok to take the input as a list of strings?

Comment: @NickKennedy strings only, no arrays ;)

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance the space is intentional for formatting purposes (example: 2019). If it wasn't there, the top row would be offset by a character making the subsequent numerals look odd.

Comment: Unless we are meant to handle the 8-digit wide digits being aligned at different points within a 10 character wide window then the first two examples are incorrectly aligned. From the two tests it looks like the alignment is meant to be a leading column of space/dot and then the 8 character wide digit and then a trailing column of space/dot. Also I assume, but should probably confirm with you, that it is OK to assume the input will have all the trailing spaces on each line, is it?

Comment: @JonathanAllan that's fine. 8 column numerics are "centered" using empty columns. You can ignore it if you wish.

Comment: ...so the first two are formatted incorrectly?

Comment: see also [Read ASCII-Art Text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115696/read-ascii-art-text)

Comment: @mazzy nice, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 34 bytes

```
Ỵe€€⁾ .¬ZḄṣ0§ḟ0%29“h½sØ?X’ḃ26¤iⱮ’Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9CsIwFIX3PsWFJlmES@kgOJT6GOJeUOnm5FZ/Rh9AQXBQcCmC4FARHeKTpC8Sc5P05yMk55Kce08WWZ6vtFbvZ1ZvSlrrL6Asp6raqdclkjdVnSMej@riNJOf5e@QTuriqKptPJTXef2422qvtQZIDEAgY4hWgbDYAscGEilhzgAGhHuHIKCDMdo595sQthUaC90xNyVJsHOY1uiOVoObYmQYhu7WLu/yYZmHniMgeYyFwrrUnLdTvAOaTzb/M0XgGyH0MpG7Vb2Qjj8)

When I started writing this, The question didn’t specify that the width of digits was fixed, so my answer doesn’t make that assumption.

Input is now a string (which costs a byte over having a list of strings). Output is an integer.

Explanation:

```
Ỵ                         | split at new lines
e€€⁾ .                    | For each character check whether it is a
                          | full stop/space or something else
      ¬                   | invert this
       Z                  | transpose
        Ḅ                 | convert from binary to decimal (one number per column of input)
         ṣ0               | split at zeroes (blank columns)
§                         | take the sum of each digit
 ḟ0                       | filter out remaining blank columns
   %29                    | take this number mod 29
      “h½sØ?X’ḃ26¤iⱮ      | look each digit up in a compressed list
                          | [18, 23, 6, 5, 1, 19, 13, 21, 8, 25]
                    ’     | subtract one
                     Ḍ    | convert to decimal
```

Comment: Minor note: The post is worded as "input must be a string", which I read as allowing a list of characters or taking input as a full program. As such I would ask if we may take a list of the lines.

Comment: @JonathanAllan fair enough. `Ỵ` added following response.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'.ð:.B€SðÊøJC0¡O0K29%•!aˆM©м•₂вskJ
```

Port of [*@NickKennedy*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181748/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
PS: Knowing the width of the digits is pretty useless if the amount of space columns in between digits can vary..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXe/wBis9p0dNa4IPbzjcdXiHl7PBoYX@Bt5GlqqPGhYpJp5u8z208sIeIPtRU9OFTcXZXv//KykpKSioAYECGCiDAIihZwsEenpgJlCWS0EFBMB8VVU4AeYqgES19RT0uIC0g4ODAlgAzAaxbCEESNQeCECKtLW1wUrAtqqp6cFNAgGQUluQKqB9YOtBZoJMBboOSoAMBLqOS0EP7CoFFKAHskUP6C8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
'.ð:                              '# Replace all dots with spaces
    .B                             # Split on newlines
      €S                           # Convert each line to a list of characters
        ðÊ                         # Check of each character if it's NOT equal to a space
          ø                        # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
           J                       # Join each column together
            C                      # Convert each from binary to an integer
             0¡                    # Split on 0s
               O                   # Sum each inner list
                0K                 # Remove 0s
                  29%              # Take modulo-29 on each
                     •!aˆM©м•      # Push compressed integer 102583844953589
                             ₂в    # Converted to Base-26 as list: 
                                   #  [18,23,6,5,1,19,13,21,8,25]
                               sk  # Index the earlier number into this list
                                 J # Join everything together (and output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•!aˆM©м•` is `102583844953589` and `•!aˆM©м•₂в` is `[18,23,6,5,1,19,13,21,8,25]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes

```
⁾. yỴ=⁶s€⁵ZẎ€Ḅ:434ị“¡£:E’Œ?’¤
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of digits, or a full program accepting a single text argument which prints the digits.

(Requires padding on the right with spaces such that each digit has a width of ten characters, including the right-most one, which I believe is OK.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZC/CsIwEMb3PsUH/bMUbrFTobSLL@HuIt2curXiJji4CS6io6OKWHAo@CDJi8TLpX/8Anchd798uayWZVkZo5sPoVLtPdPNc603N908Fuq95516bdNklqh2p@tTd@4u6VzXx@8h59hdjTFAwIKVL5JtwQKIFyhkjWXOHqa@wHaIMiuy/ZCaDXEMFzzJ8egyQHxGPT0E36GCZHIC8Yh7RJyp97OW7rlwCEVR1BOEHG6EwpXHCyaCGAmH@YLxI/4GxNCcOwE/)** ...or try the other test case [here](https://tio.run/##TY6xCsIwFEX3fMWFtlkKb7FTIejiT7i7SDenbq24CQ5ugovo6KgiFhwKfkjyIzF5aaRnuLkh992X1bKqamtN@yHUursr0z7XZnMz7WOh33vn9GtbFpNCdzvTnPpzfynnpjl@D1On/dVaC5IOgmPKeIeZhx0odwACfGfJQeENSkVBlgURo8bEQSGrOOe9b/MiXDchRURGk6bDESDBY3LYSUjigPz/g3f5RuTEGV6djHtijtw3fg).

Comment: Are you sure this works correctly? I copied the first test case, and [it gives `[1,3,4,8]` instead of `[1,3,0,6]`](https://tinyurl.com/y3hs6fcx). And I copied the second test case and [it gives `[1,5,4,4,4]` instead of `[1,8,7,4,3]`](https://tinyurl.com/y3usuyto)..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I copied the digits from the list yesterday, pre-pended a single space to each line of each of them and placed them together with a fixed-width of 10. The code does require trailing padding to 10 chars, but it looks like something else is different about the tests vs what I've done. I can't look now but if you can tell from my TIO input do let me know; I'll look later today...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ...yeah the 2 has changed since yesterday! [try it](https://tio.run/##TZC/CsIwEMZ3n@KD/lkK9wBCaV/B1d1B6eZUp0acHXQS3HQUQbAiig6FPkjzIvFyTVu/wCXc3S9fLotZluXGaPUl5M37Hmv1WOr1Raty2ry2fGqem7FWn6qcBJzUxbE61fuVLg71LqnOc327GmMAnwUrTyTHlAUQL1DA6su8jzD0@bZDFFuR7YfUbIgitGEke9S7dBDnyNFd8FpUkFgyEI/IIeJMzs9aymulxAiFYegIQoJ2hNTVuwsGghgJuvn8/iP@BnS/ASStgB8)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I believe the 1306 is formatted incorrectly and has the `6` too far to the right. [try this](https://tio.run/##VU4xCsJAEOx9xYImzcE@QDiSL9jaWyjprGKVE2sLrQQ7LUUQjIiiRSAPyX7k3N1cAk6xzM4Os7OYZVnuPbkvQt6875bcY0nrC7ly2ry2zJrnZkzuU5WTiEUqjtWp3q@oONS7pDrP6Xb13gPEDFAMBULQMhCFdccBjASiQRT1Q1dg1SBgMAKkaQphZS7MtoPVhNEbjTFq0ydxjH0itG7bGfm1FpNoCeeyYSBI15CIWhL@oB/xT/oB)

Comment: ...this was exactly why I asked about the format yesterday :)

Comment: Hmm, it is your current input (and therefore your code that's based on it) which seems to be wrong. Your current 0-9 input in your TIO has an incorrect `7,8,9` shape (a space/dot is missing at that dotted line between 6 and 7). Adding that gives incorrect results as well (although copying your test with that added dot/space gives the correct result in the other two answers). Still don't know what the problem in your code is, but it's based on an incorrect test case, and that's where the problem mainly lies.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for digging! I'll be free to address it in 4 hrs or so...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I believe this updated version works with the new `2` and that the first two examples are, in fact, misaligned ("8 column numerics are 'centered' using empty columns").